# Fitting of negative binomial distribution using statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I've got a dataset [Example data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9guguygjd946nw/Example%20data.csv?dl=0), with the arrival rate for several weeks during a specific hour.

I've found that this data is distributed as Negative Binomial.

Statsmodels provides a fitting function for this (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.html), but this requires an exog and endog input.

I think my dataset is the endog input, but what is the exog input?

As a second question, if this fitting is done, how can I get a p-value? Is this provided in the output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mean arrival rate is constant, then `exog` should be just an array of ones, i.e. `np.ones(len(data))`.

You can look at `print(results.summary())` for an overview of the results.

The results are in attributes like `params`, `bse`, `pvalues` and so on.

Answer (score -2):

- endog means dependent variables or you can say targets
- exog means independent variable